# Why do my phantomjs script output no screenshot (command line args version)

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I modified the basic phantomjs example here http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html to accept command line args.

When I pass http://google.com as argument console.log outputs are correct

> 0: index.js
>
> 1: http://google.com

but I don't get any thumbnail.png in my folder why ?

```
    var page = require('webpage').create();

    var system = require('system');
    var args = system.args;

    var url;

    if (args.length === 1) {
      url = 'http://github.com/';
    } else {
      args.forEach(function(arg, i) {
        console.log(i + ': ' + arg);
        
        if (i > 0) {
          page.open(arg, function() {

              page.render('thumbnail' + '.png');
            
            
          });
        }
        
      });
    }

    phantom.exit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`page.open` is an asynchronous function, therefore `phantom.exit` is being called before your callback to render the thumbnail.

move `phantom.exit` inside your callback as specified in the docs

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
  page.open('http://github.com/', function() {
  page.render('github.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```